# How can I output a value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "form[username]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }

  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "form[is_active]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }

  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "form[id]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
 }
```

I want to get the id from an array. The output I like to achive is `9`.

My approach:

```
echo $array['form[id]'];
```

But I don't get an output.

Comment: your id is a part of a value string  and is nota index  key ..

Comment: loop through your array and check if `array_key_exists()`

Comment: Isn't this possible without loop?

Comment: does your output have to be 9 regardless of the position?

Comment: If as you say _I cannot take the number like "2" because, in some cases the id is not on position 2_ Then you will have to loop and check for array occurance `$a["name"] == 'form[id]'`

Comment: Also note `form[id]` is the value and not the key

Comment: Ok, I understand, maybe then it is only possible with a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way might be to just first re-index the array using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). Then you can use the `name` field as the key:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'name');

echo $arr['form[id]']['value'];
// 9
```

See https://3v4l.org/L1gLR

Comment: that is the way to go :), although i dont find any need to use array like him, he can simply do like https://3v4l.org/puGKm

Answer (score 4):

When you use `$array['form[id]'];` you are looking for the key called 'form[id]' which will not work because the keys of your array are 0, 1 and 2. You can get your desired value by using `$array[2]['value']`. However this will always call the 2nd element of your array, which might not be what you want. A more dynamic solution would be something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if ($element['name'] == 'form[id]') {
        echo $element['value'];
        break;
    }
}
```

This will loop through your whole array and check the names of each element. Then when it matches your desired name it will print the value for that exact element.

Comment: You probably want to `break;` after you found it to stop iterating.

Comment: Good point. Added it!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a foreach and check for the content  .. but the content for index 'name' is just a string `form[id]` 
anyway

```
foreach( $myArray AS $key => $value){

   if ($value['name'] == 'form[id]' ) {
      echo $key;
      echo $value;

   }


}
```

Comment: You probably want to `break;` after you found it to stop iterating.

Comment: @Xatenev  thanks .. is valid suggestion  .. correct  .. the OP can use break for  end the iteration  when match

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value as if it's an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (sometimes called a dictionary or map), however it's a plain or indexed array.

Get the value you want by calling `$array[2]["value"]`

You can also use some of the higher level functions such as [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php); then you could use:

```
$id = array_search(function($values) {
  return $values['name'] == 'form[id]';
}, $array)["value"];
```

Comment: The problem is, I cannot take the number like "2" because, in some cases the id is not on position 2

Comment: Ah yes then you should loop through the array and get the `value` when the `name` value is `form[id]`

Answer (score 0):

So I think you need to filter the array to find the element you need first, then output that element's value:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, function(element){
   return element['name'] == 'form[username]';
});

if (!empty($filtered_array)) {
   echo array_pop($filtered_array)['value'];
}
```